# Removing an element of a list

Tags: python

I have a list of lists containing dictionaries:

```
[[{'event_id': 1, 'order_id': 1, 'item_id': 1, 'count': 1, 'return_count': 0, 'status': 'OK'}, 
  {'event_id': 2, 'order_id': 1, 'item_id': 1, 'count': 1, 'return_count': 0, 'status': 'OK'}],
 [{'order_id': 2, 'item_id': 1, 'event_id': 1, 'count': 3, 'return_count': 1, 'status': 'OK'}, 
  {'order_id': 2, 'event_id': 2, 'item_id': 1, 'count': 3, 'return_count': 1, 'status': 'OK'},
  {'order_id': 2, 'event_id': 1, 'item_id': 2, 'count': 4, 'return_count': 2, 'status': 'OK'}]]
```

For each item in the given order I only need those dictionaries whose `event_id` is `max`. So I wrote the following code:

```
for el in lst:
    for element in el:
        if element['event_id'] != max(x['event_id'] for x in el if element['item_id'] == x['item_id']):
            el.remove(element)
```

`lst` is the initial list.
For some reason, after running the code `lst` remains unchanged.

Comment: changing the size of the list while iterating over it is problematic in many programming languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to remove an element from a list you're iterating over, that won't work. And it's really hard to understand what you're trying to do; my suggestion would be to do something like this:

```
newlst = []
for el in lst:
    max_event_id = max(element['event_id'] for element in el)
    max_event_element = next(element for element in el if element['event_id'] == max_event_id)
    newlst.append(max_event_element)
```

The expected result ends up in the `newlst` variable.

Comment: I understood my mistake. Thank you. The problem is I also need to take into account item_id. If the item_id is different for two dictionaries then these dictionaries must not be comapred

Answer (score 1):

This isn't in one line, but it does return dictionaries with the max event id

```
dictlist = [
    [{'event_id': 1, 'order_id': 1, 'item_id': 1, 'count': 1, 'return_count': 0, 'status': 'OK'}, 
     {'event_id': 2, 'order_id': 1, 'item_id': 1, 'count': 1, 'return_count': 0, 'status': 'OK'}],
    [{'order_id': 2, 'item_id': 1, 'event_id': 1, 'count': 3, 'return_count': 1, 'status': 'OK'}, 
     {'order_id': 2, 'event_id': 2, 'item_id': 1, 'count': 3, 'return_count': 1, 'status': 'OK'},
     {'order_id': 2, 'event_id': 1, 'item_id': 2, 'count': 4, 'return_count': 2, 'status': 'OK'}]]

max = 0
parsed = []
for item in dictlist:
    for i in item:
        if i['event_id'] > max:
            max = i['event_id']
for item in dictlist:
    for dic in item:
        if dic['event_id'] == max:
            parsed.append(dic)
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with multi-line code; many programmers find it easier to understand, maintain and modify than one-liners/comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

`sort` on "event_id" and keep only the max (last element):

```
result = [sorted(l, key=lambda x: x["event_id"])[-1] for l in lst]
```

If you want to keep all dictionaries with the max "event_id":

```
lsts = [[x for x in l if x["event_id"]==max(l, key=lambda x: x["event_id"])["event_id"]] for l in lst]
result = [item for sublist in lsts for item in lsts]
```

Comment: this would only keep one element with event id, in the example data there are multiple elements that want to be kept

Comment: In the example there is only one `event_id` for each `order_id` which corresponds to the max. But I see how there could be multiple. Edited.

Comment: for the first one - can be shorter if you'll remove the "reverse" keyword argument and pick the last element

Comment: @absofacto - Brilliant suggestion! :)

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain the problem in the right way. If the  item_id is different within same order_id, then these two should not be compared.